# Docker http://localhost:8000 it is not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and tried to install WordPress in Docker

```
Details are : 
OS : Windows 10 Home
Docker Version : Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
```

I done following steps

```yaml
version: '3.3'
  services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
  volumes:
    - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mysql
    MYSQL_USER: admin
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
  image: wordpress:latest
  ports:
    - "8000:80"
  restart: always
  environment:
    WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
    WORDPRESS_DB_USER: admin
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: admin
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: admin
  volume:
    db_data: {}
```

It is working fine

```
$ docker ps                                                                                                                                            CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
944e0ea8ff69        wordpress:latest    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   wordpress_wordpress_1
5a3890fed7fe        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   45 minutes ago      Up 45 minutes       6379/tcp               sleepy_matsumoto
4edf3f9fc944        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up 38 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp    wordpress_db_1
```

But when I am running http://localhost:8000 or http://localhost:80 in browser it is showing site is not reachable. How can I resolve this?

Comment: not sure, did you check windows firewall? Can you check the port is binded https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28609/how-can-i-tell-what-is-listening-on-a-tcpip-port-in-windows/

Comment: Try `docker-compose logs`. If there is an error, post it in your question.

Comment: it is checked PS C:\temp> netstat -aon | findstr 8080
PS C:\temp> netstat -aon | findstr 8000

Comment: docker-compose logs showing complete log having thousands of lines can you suggest how to upload this log or command for looking errors

Comment: I've just tried your compose file. It seems to be full of errors. I don't have time to fix them. Can you paste the file you used pls?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: ok, it is not for offending anyone but to install wordpress and give it to vendor for doing his work

Comment: @software engineer it the same file i have put it in a question and filename i have used filename docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer for this problem details are as under as I have installed docker using Docker Toolbox

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v19.03.5
```

Now if I do

http://192.168.99.100:8000/

Now finally it is working. Hopefully it will help you too